# How to use inset dividers in RecyclerView using AndroidX?

Tags: android

I have read many posts about dividers in RecyclerViews but I did not find any implementation example of an **inset dividers** as suggested by Material Design:

[image]

This picture is taken from https://material.io/components/dividers#types. So I am looking for a divider that is aligned with the text on the left. **Can anyone tell me how to implement such a divider using AndroidX?**

**EDIT:**

This is my layout that contains the RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/offeringsCoordLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/offerings_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar.DragScrollBar
        android:id="@+id/dragScrollBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:msb_recyclerView="@id/offerings_recyclerview"
        app:msb_lightOnTouch="false"
        app:msb_handleColor="@color/accent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <include layout="@layout/resourcesview_empty"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialOverlayLayout
    android:id="@+id/offerings_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:clickable_overlay="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
    android:id="@+id/speedDialOfferings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:sdMainFabClosedBackgroundColor="@color/accent"
    app:sdMainFabOpenedSrc="@drawable/ic_pencil_black"
    app:sdMainFabOpenedBackgroundColor="@color/accent"
    app:sdMainFabClosedIconColor="@android:color/white"
    app:sdMainFabOpenedIconColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/speeddial_scrolling_view_snackbar_behavior"
    app:sdOverlayLayout="@id/offerings_overlay"/>
```

Individual row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listicon_imageview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/listicon_imageview"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/date_offeringlist_item"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:text="Burnt offering"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_offeringlist_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Burnt offering"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/verses_offeringlist_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:text="verses" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/experience_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/verses_offeringlist_item"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/verses_offeringlist_item"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:text="experience" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_offered_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/experience_offeringslist_item"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DividerItemDecoration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` for that, check code below:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class InsetDividerItemDecoration(
    context: Context,
    private val insetDividerLeft: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private val attributesArray = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.listDivider)

    private var dividerDrawable: Drawable? = null

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributesArray)
        dividerDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0)
        if (dividerDrawable == null) {
            Log.w("InsetDivider", "@android:attr/listDivider was not set in the theme used here")
        }
        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        if (parent.layoutManager == null || dividerDrawable == null) {
            return
        }

        val left = parent.paddingLeft + insetDividerLeft
        val right = parent.width - parent.paddingRight

        for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)

            val params = child.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
            val top = child.bottom + params.bottomMargin
            val bottom: Int = top + (dividerDrawable?.intrinsicHeight ?: 0)

            dividerDrawable?.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
            dividerDrawable?.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
    ) = if (dividerDrawable == null) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0)
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, dividerDrawable?.intrinsicHeight ?: 0)
    }

}
```

The code above was inspired by [`DividerItemDecoration`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DividerItemDecoration.java;).

---

Now that we have the new custom `ItemDecoration`, you can add it to the `RecyclerView`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    // Ideally you would load the offsets from a dimensions file, 
    // and that is how you could easily support RTL as well.
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(InsetDividerItemDecoration(view.context, 64.toPx()))
    ...
}

fun Int.toPx() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

### Edit

I created a [Github repo](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/-Stackoverflow-InsetDividerItemDecoration) showcasing this solution in action

Comment: Thanks, but your solution moves the whole item to the right, not the divider. The divider is not changed at all.

Comment: You are right, you actually need `onDraw` to achieve that. Please check the updated answer/code!

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it does not work for me. Take a look at what is happening when I implement your code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12jZt81l4VdFR1XnKtW7m04jGpI4PxCnL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I added a link with no permissions to open it... here is the correct link to my screen shot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12jZt81l4VdFR1XnKtW7m04jGpI4PxCnL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works fine, I suspect that one of the parent views of this `RecyclerView` has a background color, try adding `android:background="@android:color/white"` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: I added my layout.xml which contains the RecyclerView. I tried setting the background to white, but it won't work. Can you take a look at my Layout? I have already tried to comment out some of the third-party components, but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you add the recyclerview item layout as well.

Comment: The recyclerView is insinde the posted parent layout, or what do you mean?

Comment: I meant the individual `RecyclerView` row layout

Comment: OK, I added the individual row layout. See above.

Comment: Thanks @to_sam, I fixed a few bugs in the custom `ItemDecoration` and created a Github repo showcasing it in action

Comment: Wow, nice! Now it is working! At first, I had the problem that I set the decoration before the adapter. That, of course, did not work.